# summarizing data except one type of value in one column in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(name= c( "a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c"),
             type= c("imp","imp","imp","imp","exp","imp","imp","imp"),
             value= c(1,2,2,2,6,3,4,5))
```

I want to summarize values grouping by name and type. but the c and their values should be stay same like :

```
  new_df <- data.frame(name= c( "a","b", "b","c","c","c"),
               type= c("imp","imp","exp","imp","imp","imp"),
               sum_value= c(3,4,6,3,4,5))
```

thanks for all help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new column with unique values for `c` and group by that column:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(gp = ifelse(name == "c", paste0(name, row_number()), name), .by = name) %>% 
  summarise(sum_value = sum(value), .by = c(gp, type))

  gp type sum_value
1  a  imp         3
2  b  imp         4
3  b  exp         6
4 c1  imp         3
5 c2  imp         4
6 c3  imp         5
```

Or split and bind:

```r
df %>% 
  filter(name != "c") %>% 
  summarise(value = sum(value), .by = c(name, type)) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% filter(name == "c"))

  name type value
1    a  imp     3
2    b  imp     4
3    b  exp     6
4    c  imp     3
5    c  imp     4
6    c  imp     5
```

Answer (score 2):

I was going to suggest something similar but using `dplyr::case_when()` instead of `ifelse()`. And, using multiple grouping variables to get the desired output.

```
df %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    gp = dplyr::case_when(
      name == "c" ~ as.character(dplyr::row_number()),
      TRUE ~ name
    )
  ) %>%
  dplyr::group_by(name, type, gp) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(sum = sum(value)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-gp)
```

which results in what you want, just ordered differently.

```
# A tibble: 6 × 3
# Groups:   name, type [4]
  name  type    sum
  <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 a     imp       3
2 b     exp       6
3 b     imp       4
4 c     imp       3
5 c     imp       4
6 c     imp       5
```

Comment: thank you. that is the solution  what I want to have.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different `dplyr` approach:

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.1.0

df %>% 
  filter(name != "c") %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value), .by = c(name, type)) %>% 
  bind_rows(df %>% 
              filter(name == "c"))

  name type value
1    a  imp     3
2    b  imp     4
3    b  exp     6
4    c  imp     3
5    c  imp     4
6    c  imp     5
```